# wxpython gridtable how to update

Tags: wxpython

So this app designed to open a csv file containing DJI stock data. The csv file looks as below:

[image]

The app so far looks like as below:

[image]

**My question is how to update the data table by user input:**
For example: user can type in in the company code, and hit enter so the table would be filtered to be just showing the information match to the type in code.

tried in onEnter(). Not working,returned:

```
free():invalid pointer
Aborted (Core dump)
```

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

class MyDataTable(gridlib.GridTableBase):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        gridlib.GridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.headerRows = 0
        if data is None:
            data = pd.DataFrame()

        self.data = data

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def GetNumberCols(self):
        return len(self.data.columns) + 1



class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Frame class that display data"""
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size = (1000,2000))

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        # PANEL
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1) # set id = -1
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('White')

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu1 = wx.Menu()

        openMenuItem = menu1.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, '&Open', 'Open a file in a dialog')
        menu1.AppendSeparator() # add a separator
        closeMenuItem = menu1.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit', 'Close the dialog')
        menuBar.Append(menu1, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        # input widgets
        label_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, 'Company Code:', pos=(0, 5))
        self.text_enter = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "", pos=(110, 1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB | wx.TE_CENTER | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.checkBox1 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, "Open Price", (0,50))
        self.checkBox2 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, "Highest Price", (100,50))
        self.checkBox3 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, "Lowest Price", (220,50))
        self.checkBox4 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, "Close Price", (340,50))
        self.checkBox5 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1, "Volume", (450,50))
        plot_button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Plot", pos=(550, 50))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onOpen, openMenuItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onClose, closeMenuItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.onEnter, self.text_enter)


    def onOpen(self, event):
        filepath = None
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open CSV File", "", "", "csv files(*.csv) |*.csv", wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return
        filepath = openFileDialog.GetPath() # path
        #make a grid table
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self.panel, id=2, pos=(0, 100), size = (800, 500))
        self.df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=0)
        self.table = MyDataTable(self.df)
        grid = gridlib.Grid(self, 2, pos=(0, 100), size=(self.table.GetNumberRows(), self.table.GetNumberCols()))
        grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        grid.SetColLabelSize(30)
        grid.SetTable(self.table)
        grid.AutoSize()
        grid.AutoSizeColumns(True)

        openFileDialog.Destroy()


    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def onEnter(self, event):
        df2 = self.df[self.df['Codes'] == self.text_enter]
        self.table = MyDataTable(df2)
        grid = gridlib.Grid(self, 2, pos=(0, 100), size=(self.table.GetNumberRows(), self.table.GetNumberCols()))
        grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        grid.SetColLabelSize(30)
        grid.SetTable(self.table)
        grid.AutoSize()
        grid.AutoSizeColumns(True)
```

Comment: You need to do three things:  1.  Split this question up.  It's too broad as it is, you shouldn't be asking three questions at once.  2.  In the separated questions, provide tracebacks for the errors you're receiving.  3.  Try to minimize the amount of code you're supplying.  See: [mcve]

Comment: Edited as instructed to focus on how to update the gridtable by user input.